# Mongodb query using $and operator slow with three conditions

Tags: mongodb

I am using the $and operator in the find() method with three conditions to satisfy. The issue is that, there are no results returned and the query is unresponsive.

This is not the case when I use two conditions. When I use two conditions, the query is fast and results are returned immediately.

Why is this and how can I resolve this ?

Comment: Did you run an `explain` and see what your query is actually doing -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/? See how the query execution plan differs when you run with two conditions vs three conditions.

Comment: Do you have any indexes set on the collection and what does the extra $and condition look like? Also, how many documents are in the collection?